# How can I use a Ruby variable in an inline JavaScript in haml?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have the following variable in my controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def my_method
    @status = "status"
  end
end
```

In my `haml` view, I tried following, but it doesn't work (since it's using the default .erb syntax):

```
#app/views/mycontroller/me_method.html.haml

:javascript
  alert(<%=raw @status %>)
```

How can I use the `@status` variable inside my inline JavaScript?

Comment: Except the possible typo `my_method` with `me_method` I can't find anything wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the simple "#{}" interpolation tags to use ruby variables with HAML.

Your code:

```
:javascript
    alert(<%=raw @status %>)
```

Possible Solution:

```
:javascript
    alert("#{@status}")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the normal string interpolation syntax (`#{}`).

```
#app/views/mycontroller/me_method.html.haml

:javascript
  alert(#{raw @status})
```

See also this previous SO question:

[Inline ruby in :javascript haml tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120292/inline-ruby-in-javascript-haml-tag)

Answer (score 2):

Just like you would do in a ruby string :

```
:javascript
  alert("#{raw @status}")
```